# Explicit construction for Cohen’s $p$-ring with imperfect residual field

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, witt-vectors

Apologize if this is a below-research-level question. Asked in [stack exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4721692/explicit-construction-for-cohen-s-p-ring-with-imperfect-residual-field) but no response yet.

Let $p>0$ be a prime. Recall that a $p$-ring is a complete DVR $A$ with residual filed $k$ of characteristic $p$ such that $p$ is a uniformizer.

It is known (e.g. Ch 29. of Matsumura’s *Commutative Ring Theory*) that for any field $k$ of characteristic $p$ there is a unique (up to isomorphism) $p$-ring with residual field $k$.

The ring of Witt vectors $A=W(k)$ offers an explicit construction for **perfect** $k$, e.g. Serre’s *Local Fields*.

Is there a similar description when $k$ is **imperfect**? If so, what is it? Any reference(s)?

Comment: How explicit do you want it? Bourbaki's *Algèbre Commutative* chapter IX section 2 is, I think, as explicit as it can get, with theorem 2 explicitly constructing more general versions of Cohen subrings inside certain local rings $A$. Yours is a special case which can be constructed, for imperfect $k$, as subring of the Witt vectors $W(k)$. And prop. 4 shows a more general and precise version of uniqueness / universal property.

Comment: If you read German: The special case you are interested in is treated in section 7 of https://ivv5hpp.uni-muenster.de/u/pschnei/publ/lectnotes/Theorie-des-Anstiegs.pdf.